# How to check if there are duplicates among a field within as set of data?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table ( real table has abit more fields but these are the important aspects ) :

***GameID,Team***

```
1000,A
1000,A
1000,B

1001,A
1001,B
1001,C

1002,A
1002,B
```

The GameID represents a game where there can be many players, so in the above there are 3 games.

Team represents the team that played in the game.

Currently my datasets have games where the 2 from the same team can be playing against each other 
but i would like to filter these out and get a list of ID's of which games has same team playing
against each other.

If each player is from different team this is perfectly OK - but i need to do another calculation on score
in the matches that has players from same team playing in a game.

Is there a smart way of getting this extracted in SQLite ?

Comment: could you please provide your expected output in table format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use aggregation

```
select GameID,Team,count(*)
from table_name
group by GameID,Team
having count(*)>1
```